# NuGet - Install Package Programmatically (Multiple Sources)

Tags: c#, nuget

The following article describes how to install packages programmatically:

http://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html

I have used one of the overloads to make sure it also installs the dependencies. However one of the dependencies for the pack I'm installing is not within the same source/feed.

Is it possible to specify multiple sources?

Comment: +1 for showing me that blog post! I was hunting for a way to use nuget programmatically and for the life of me couldn't find how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a PackageRepository for each of your package sources and then put them into an AggregateRepository. You can then use the AggregateRepository instead of the single IPackageRepository since it implements that interface.

The AggregateRepository takes a list of IPackageRepository in its constructor.

```
 public AggregateRepository(IEnumerable<IPackageRepository> repositories)
 {
 }
```

Comment: Thanks this looks exactly what I'm after. I'll test this first thing in the morning when I get to work. Thanks again.